# Create a python dataframe using string of variable

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a function for running a logistic regression model. I would like to permanently save the dataframe generated within (cf) and amend it's name.

```
def model(ind, dep):
    global cf
    ind.fillna(0)
    #some modelling code

    #create confuson matix

    cf = pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix(y_train, y_pred))
    cf.index = models
    cf.columns = models
    print(cf)
    cf.plot.barh()


    "cf_" + str(ind) = cf

    return "cf_" + str(ind)

model(X_tv, y_combo)
model(X_tv_chan, y_combo)
```

I get this error

File "", line 64
    "cf_" + str(ind) = coeff
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

is there something wrong with how I am trying to create the dataframe?

```
"cf_" + str(ind) = cf
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This line doesn't create a new variable:

```
"cf_" + str(ind) = cf
```

Strings are immutable. You can't "assign a dataframe to a string" either, I'm not even sure what this is attempting to achieve. It's also good practice to avoid `global` variables.

Just return your dataframe and assign to an explicit variable name. If you are set on changing your variable name, use a dictionary and `dict.pop`:

```
def model(ind, dep):
    # ...
    cf = pd.DataFrame(confusion_matrix(y_train, y_pred))
    cf.index = models
    cf.columns = models
    # ...
    return cf

dfs = {}

dfs['ind'] = model(X_tv, y_combo)  # identify dataframe with key 'ind'
dfs['cf_ind'] = dfs.pop('ind')     # rename identifier to 'cf_ind'
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a number of dataframes I want to pull out of the function and save. In the end I have used the global options and then returned then. Then in between each call of the function I have appended the new table.model                                                      (X_tv, y_combo, 'just_trans')
masterCM=masterCM.append(cf)
masterCOEFF=masterCOEFF.append(coeff)

model(X_tv_cattot, y_combo, 'trans_cattotals')
masterCM=masterCM.append(cf)
masterCOEFF=masterCOEFF.append(coeff)

Comment: `I want to pull out of the function and save`. That's what this does: `dfs['ind'] = model(X_tv, y_combo)`. Please don't post code in comments, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53224522/edit) to clarify your question.